# Why does Java find one referenced class but not another in the same .jar?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

If I run:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/OLSMultipleLinearRegression
```

However, if I run:

```
java -classpath '.:commons-math3-3.2.jar' -jar myjar.jar
```

I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/special/Erf
```

Any idea why this happened?

I just don't compute how the `-classpath` option can solve the "Class Not Found" error for one class but not for the other, when both classes do exist in the .jar added.

Or did I invoke the .jar incorrectly?

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: I edited and clarified.

Comment: `-classpath` has no effect when you use `-jar`, IIRC. Yup, just checked: "When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored." So I'm surprised it has any effect at all.

Comment: Make sure you include all your dependencies as class path attributes in the MANIFEST.MF file inside your jar.

Comment: @JonSkeet If that is so, can I probably merge the 2 jars producing a myjar.jar that already has the library inside? and how?

Comment: ah I see, I can modify the manifest. that should solve it. thanks guys

Comment: @Billiska: That's one option, but another is to specify the jar files it depends on in your manifest, as NilsH suggests.